# Spring MVC : Redirecting from a base controller - How to get the path to redirect to?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have searched and searched and have not found anything that says this is not possible, nor anything that explains how to do it.

If you have a Base Controller that is extended I understand that the request mapped methods are also inherited.

So with....

```
public abstract class BaseController
{

    @RequestMapping(value="hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(Model model) {
        return "hello-view;
}
```

...a Controller like so ...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/")
public abstract class AdminController
{
 ....
}
```

...will inherit a method listening at /admin/hello that returns the hello-view.

This is all fine.

But what if I have a BaseController method that redirects:

```
public abstract class BaseController
{

    @RequestMapping(value="hello", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String hello(Model model) {
        return "redirect:/success/;
}
```

As I understand it the redirect requires either a relative or absolute URL rather than a viewname?

So how does my AdminController ensure the redirect takes place to /admin/success/?

How does the BaseController method get a handle on the class level @requestMapping on my AdminController?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option:

```
public abstract class BaseController
{
    /** get the context for the implementation controller **/
    protected abstract String getControllerContext();

    @RequestMapping(value="hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(Model model) {
        return "redirect:"+getControllerContext()+"success/";
    }
}
```

and here's the admin controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(AdminController.context)
public abstract class AdminController
{
    static final String context = "/admin/";
    @Override
    protected String getControllerContext() {
        return context;
    }
 ....
}
```

Another option that involves reflection that might work...:

```
public abstract class BaseController
{
    String context = null;

    @RequestMapping(value="hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(Model model) {
        return "redirect:"+getControllerContext()+"success/";
    }

    // untested code, but should get you started.
    private String getControllerContext() {
        if ( context == null ) {
            Class klass = this.getClass();
            Annotation annotation = klass.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            if ( annotation != null ) {
                context = annotation.value();
            }
        }
        return context;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow - 
"Annotation annotation = klass.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);" has the magic - couldn't see that anywhere! cheers- wonderful! oh yes and @RequestMapping(AdminController.context) too. Cheers for the lesson!

Answer (score 3):

According http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix
`redirect:/myapp/some/resource` will redirect relative to the current Servlet context.

My check: Application context is `topjava`, Servlet context is `meals`, 
request `http://localhost:8080/topjava/meals/update?...`

redirected by `redirect:meals` to http://localhost:8080/topjava/meals/meals

redirected by `redirect:/meals` to http://localhost:8080/topjava/meals

Answer (score 1):

In Spring no need to give relative url like

```
"redirect:/admin/success/";
```

instead of above code, directly you can give like this

```
"redirect:/success/";
```

By default it will take the context path.

Comment: context path and controller requestmappings are different things though. I was interested in getting the controller requestmappings....

Answer (score -1):

As long as you don't need anything dynamic i would just redirect to the requestmapping in the string. Haven't used redirect myself yet but the mapping for your admin success would be:

`return "redirect:/admin/success/"`

This should create a browser redirect to your controller with the corresponding requestmapping.

Another possibilty would be to use reflection and grab the requestmapping annotation your parent.

Comment: The redirect takes place in the parent class but it needs to inject the context from the child class into the redirect string. If there are multiple implementations of the abstract base class then hard coding the redirect string isn't reasonable. In one case they want to go to /admin/success and in another implementation they want to go to /user/success.

Comment: Aye true. Don't know why i missed that! Your answer is a good possibility.